# Parrallel Working But Not To Desired Effect

Tags: c++, arrays

I was given a assignment in college. I was asked to create a c++ console application that would read in five countries from a simple .txt file and allow a user to allocate each team a vote [6, 8, 10, 12]. Each team may vote only once, no duplicate scores and they may not vote for themselves.
We have to then display the scores in descending order to the user using a bubble sort. Practically every element of the application was working up until I had to print the scores in order.
I'm having difficulty with the calculation of the total score and also with the while loop in 'getValidCountry()'

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>      // include the 'fstream' standard library header file 
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//VARIABLES
#define POINTS 4
#define NUM_COUNTRIES 5
int points[POINTS] = {6, 8, 10, 12};
vector<string> countries; 
int countryInd[NUM_COUNTRIES] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int votes [NUM_COUNTRIES][NUM_COUNTRIES];
int voteTotal[NUM_COUNTRIES] = {0,0,0,0,0};

//METHOD HEADINGS
void printarray (int arg[], int length);
void voting(int votingCountry);
int getValidVote();
void printRankedTable();
void printContestants();
void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n);
void resetPoints();
int getValidCountry();

int main ()
{
    ifstream inFile;  
    inFile.open("countries.txt");   // bind the inFile stream to a file name  
    if( !inFile )                // test to see if it opened successfully  
    {  
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;     
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  
    }

    int i = 0; 
    string str;  
    string fileContents;  

    //RESERVE 5 SPACES IN THE VECTOR
    countries.reserve(NUM_COUNTRIES);
    vector<string>::iterator iter;


    while( getline( inFile, str ) )  
    {  
        countries.push_back(str);
    }  
    inFile.close();

    printContestants();
    int round = 5;
    int cInd = -1;

    while(round > 0)
    {
        cout << endl;

        cInd = getValidCountry();
        voting(cInd);

        BubbleSort(voteTotal, NUM_COUNTRIES);
        printRankedTable();

        cInd = -1;
        round--;
    }

}

int getValidCountry()
{
    bool temp = false;
    string foo;

    cout << "Enter Country You Wish To Vote For: ";
    getline(cin, foo);

    while(!temp)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; i++)
        {
            if(foo.compare(countries.at(countryInd[i])) == 0)
            {
                temp = true;
                return countryInd[i];
            }
        }
        cout << "[ERROR]: Enter A Valid Country: ";
        getline(cin, foo);
    }
    return -1;
}


void printarray (int arg[], int length) {
    for (int n=0; n<length; ++n)
        cout << arg[n] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

void voting(int votingCountry)
{
    int score = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; i++)
    {
        if(countryInd[i] != votingCountry)
        {
            cout << "Please Enter Score For " << countries.at(countryInd[i]) << ": ";
            score = getValidVote();
            cout << score << endl;
            voteTotal[countryInd[i]] = voteTotal[countryInd[i]] + score;
            cout << "vote total: " << voteTotal[countryInd[i]] << "\t CountryInd: " << countryInd[i] << endl;
        }

    }

    resetPoints();
    cout << endl;
}

void resetPoints()
{
    points[0] = 6;
    points[1] = 8;
    points[2] = 10;
    points[3] = 12;

}


int getValidVote()
{
    bool isValid = false;
    int vote;
    while(!isValid)
    {
        cin >> vote;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= POINTS; i++)
        {
            if (vote == points[i] && vote > -1)
            {
                isValid = true;
                points[i] = -1;
                return vote;
            }
        }
        cout << "Enter Valid Score: ";
    }
    return 0;

}


void printContestants()
{
    cout << endl << "EUROVISION CONTESTANTS\n";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; i++)
    {
        cout << countries[countryInd[i]] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

void printRankedTable()
{
    cout << endl << "EUROVISION CONTESTANTS [RANKED]\n";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTRIES; i++)
    {
        cout << countries.at(countryInd[i]) << "\t" << voteTotal[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}

void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{
    bool swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    int tmpC;
    while (swapped) 
    {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) 
            {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                tmpC = countryInd[i];
                countryInd[i] = countryInd[i+1];
                countryInd[i+1] = tmpC;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.` [`See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's not a bubble sort.  It looks like that bubble sort function returns as soon as it bubbles up a single item to the top.

Comment: It works nonetheless. I'm happy with the sorting function. My Main problem is the voteTotal function

Comment: True: the sorting function sorts well.  Unfortunatly by sorting both the scores and the access sequence to countries, you create a mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

When you are `voting()`, you enter the score to `voteTotal` using `countryInd` index:

```
voteTotal[countryInd[i]] = voteTotal[countryInd[i]] + score;  // in voting()
```

So you expect that the order of the countries names and their related score id both use the access sequence defined in `countryInd[]`.

```
// score of countries.at(countryInd[i]) corresponds to valueTotal[countryInd[i]]
```

When you `BubbleSort()`, you swap the elements in both `countryInd[]` AND in `voteTotal[]`.  This is the cause of your problem, because the right access sequence for the country names is still countryInd[i] but it's now i for the score:

```
//score of countries.at(countryInd[i]) corresponds now to valueTotal[i]
```

You already know this, because that's exactly the logic you use in `printRankedTable()`

Unfortunately, when you take the second voting run, you assume again that both tables use the same access sequence defined in `countryInd[]` , which is an hypotheses which is no longer valid. You end up adding the voting given for one country to the total of another.

**The solution**

Change in `BubbleSort()` the if clause as follows:

```
if (arr[countryInd[i]] < arr[countryInd[i + 1]]) // indirect access through countryInd
        {
            //tmp = arr[i];           delete => no longuer needed
            //arr[i] = arr[i + 1];    delete => no longuer needed
            //arr[i + 1] = tmp;       delete => no longuer needed
            tmpC = countryInd[i];
            countryInd[i] = countryInd[i + 1];
            countryInd[i + 1] = tmpC;
            swapped = true;
        }
```

Also update the `printRankedTable()` the output instruction to:

```
 cout << countries.at(countryInd[i]) << "\t" << voteTotal[countryInd[i]] << endl;  // only indirect access via countryInd
```